# How can I remove Bittorrent from Ubuntu?

Tags: bittorrent

Hi I went to download OpenSUSE from Distrowatch and selected the bit torrent download.

The download distro appeared in "My Downloads" within seconds. It usually take 3 hours for a distro to download on my system. However about an hour later I could not get it to burn to DVD disk.

There also appears to be two parts to it which I have not experienced before.  Previously all my d/l had only one file.

I am also worried about my security due to the p2p aspect, and I don't like not being able to see the download in progress.

Is there anyway I can remove this application from Ubuntu? If not, how safe is it to leave it installed? Can I stop it taking over so that I can download distros as I used to?

Comment: Seems to me that you downloaded the .torrent file from distrowatch, and would need to actually open that file in Transmission for the OpenSUSE .iso to download.

Comment: Distrowatch don't provide hotlinks to any torrent. This link http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=suse has a entry for *Download Mirrors" that points to http://software.opensuse.org/ and there you can download SUSE. Please, include the `xdg-mime query default application/x-bittorrent` output to check if some other rouge client is installed.

Answer (score 8):

Transmission is the Bittorrent client installed by default. You can remove this if you wish and the following command should do the job:

```
sudo apt-get remove transmission-common
```

### However...

- As Luis points out in the comments, it sounds like you never actually started the download. You downloaded a torrent file (which needs to be loaded into a torrent client - like Transmission). A torrent is just a description of stuff to download. That's why the download was so fast and wouldn't burn to DVD.
- When you start a torrent properly it does let you know the progress. There should be a Transmission icon sitting in your tray (looks like a gearstick in an automatic car) and if not, just load Transmission.
- There are no "security" issues with P2P. If you mean legal issues, that only applies if you're downloading things you have no license for. Bittorrent is a safe way of transporting files. Having it installed is not against the law. Using it illegally is.
- Bittorrent also performs CRC checks on the sections of the file you're transferring. It's therefore more likely you'll see errors in standard downloads than in torrent downloads.
- It also isn't taking over. **It can't.** If you're downloading a .torrent file, (respectfully) that's your fault. If you want a non-torrent version of something, download that instead.

Distributions use (and prefer) Bittorrent because of these reasons. It's also less bandwidth intensive for them to manage (because you'll download it from other people with copies too). It's also generally pretty fast because the download is split over multiple hosts. Everybody wins.